# Azure IoT Central: Create device template from rest request

Tags: azure, rest, azure-iot-central

we want to deploy and configure an IoT Central with Infrastructure as Code (IaC). After creating the IoT-Central from a default template (iotc-pnp-preview@1.0.0) with pulumi, we get an IoT Central application without devices and without device templates. To automate the deployment further we want to configure the devices and device templates from a script, too. This is where we are facing some problems:

If we execute the commands from the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-manage-device-templates-with-rest-api) we get the following error:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "NotFound",
> "message": ""undefined" is not a valid API version. You can contact support at https://aka.ms/iotcentral-support. Please include the following information. Request ID: 8uzlc76s, Time: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 12:48:21 GMT.",
> "requestId": "8uzlc76s",
> "time": "Mon, 29 Nov 2021 12:48:21 GMT"
> }
> }

[image: Screenshot of Postman with Restrequest]

Please note that other rest requests are working as expected. e.g. the Request to list all available device templates (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/1.0dataplane/device-templates/get) returns:

> {
> "value": []
> }

That's why we assume authentification and url are correct.

Can you tell me why my attempt to create a device template from rest interface fails? What do I need to do different to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following screen snippet shows a successful response on the [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/1.1-previewdataplane/device-templates/create), note, that is a version 1.1-preview:

[image]

Comment: thanks! using 1.1-preview worked.